# How to set the table structure in html with multiple for each loop?

Tags: php, css, html, cakephp

I want to set the structure in table product against plan, i want to show like that

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| product1         | product2      | product3      |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| product1plan1    | product2plan1 | product3plan1 |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+ 
| prouduct1plan2   | product2plan2 |               |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
| product1plan3    |               |               |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

but now it showing me like that

```
  product1 | product1plan1 | product1plan2  product2 | product2plan1 | product2plan1
```

here is my code

```
 <table>
<thead>
     <tr>
    <?php 
       foreach( $name as $product ) {
        $c = 0;
        foreach ($product as $key ) {
            $c++;
            ?>              
       <th>
                 <?php echo $key['Product']['name']; ?>
         <?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof( $key['ProductPlan'] ); $i++ ) { ?>
         <th class= 'packages' id = "<?php echo $key['Product']['name'], $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>" 
           onclick = "document.getElementById('<?php echo $key['Product']['name']?>').value='<?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>';"
                >
            <div product_name='<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>' class='amounts amount-<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>'>
               <div class='tick'>
                  <?php echo $this->Html->image('tick.png', array('width'=>'25', 'height'=>'25'));?>
              </div>
             <div class='amount'>
         <?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['name'];?> $
             </div>
          </div>            
           </th>
           <?php } ?>
       </th>
     <?php } ?>         
   <?php } ?>
</tr>
  </thead>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little hard to figure this out without seeing the working example, but looking at the code in your question, you have a th tag inside a th tag, which is why you are seeing the results you are.  I believe if you replace the inner th tag with a div tag, that should solve the issue.

However, the th tag is really supposed to be used for the table heading, or in your example, the product name.  In order to do that, you will need 2 loops: 1 to create the table headings with the product names and a second to print out the plans (in a table cell in a row beneath your header).

Try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($name as $product) {
                        foreach ($product as $key) {
                            echo $key['Product']['name'];
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php 
                foreach($name as $product) {
                    $c = 0;
            ?>

            <?php 
                foreach ($product as $key) {
                $c++;
            ?>

            <td>
                <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($key['ProductPlan']);$i++) { ?>

                <div class   = 'packages'
                     id      = "<?php echo $key['Product']['name'],$key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>" 
                     onclick = "document.getElementById('<?php echo $key['Product']['name']?>').value='<?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>';"
                >

                    <div product_name='<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>' class='amounts amount-<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>'>
                        <div class='tick'>
                            <?php echo $this->Html->image('tick.png', array('width'=>'25', 'height'=>'25'));?>
                        </div>

                        <div class='amount'>
                            <?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['name'];?> $
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
            </td>

            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are almost close to the the answer, i just edit the code in <thead>------- </thead> section, and the result will be as i want. Thanks joni.